# Analogous proof for coset equality

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am self studying abstract algebra, so please bear with me if this is
obvious to you.

I came across this when reading "A Book of Abstract Algebra" by
Charles C. Pinter. In page 124 ([electronic
version](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jcohen/402/Pinter%20Algebra.pdf),
UMD released it so I figure it's ok to put a link here), he states:

> If $a\in Hb$, then $Ha = Hb$

Here's his proof:

> Let $x\in Ha$; this means that $x=h_2a$ for some $h_2\in H$. But $a = h_1b$,
>     so $x=h_2a =(h_2h_1)b$, and the latter is clearly in $Hb$; *analogously,
>     we may show that every $y\in Hb$ is in $Ha$, and therefore $Ha=Hb$.*

My question arises when I try to prove that every $y\in Hb$ is in $Ha$, I
found the analogous way doesn't work. Let me walk through.

Let $y \in Hb$; this means that $y=h_2b$ for some $h_2 \in H$. But $b =
h_1a$, ....

Wait a sec, I think we can't say $b = h_1a$ for some $h_1\in H$, since
$b$ is just an element in $G$, not $Ha$, right?

In such case, how to prove $Ha = Hb$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you *can* say that $b = ha$ for some $h \in H$! This is simply because, if $a = hb$ for some $h \in H$, which follows from the fact that $a \in Hb$, we multiply by $h^{-1}$ on both sides to get $$h^{-1} a = h^{-1}(hb) = (h^{-1}h)b = eb = b$$ Since $H$ is a subgroup, $h^{-1} \in H$ because $H$ is closed under inverse. Take $h_1 = h^{-1}$ to see that $b = h_1a$. So yes, this implies $b \in Ha$, but not immediately (we cannot jump to this conclusion, there was an intermediate step).

Now the argument is analogous : if $y\in Hb$, $y = h_2b = h_2(h_1 a) = (h_2h_1)a \in Ha$. Hence, $Hb \subset Ha$ and the conclusion follows.